# multiprocess a function with a element of list as argument

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to acheive multi processing in python. I might have a minimum of 500 elements in the list at least. I have a function to which each element of a list needs to be passed as an argument. Then each of this function should be executed as a seperate process using mutli processing either starting a new interpretter or however. Following is some pseudo code.

```
def fiction(arrayElement)
        perform some operations here

arrayList[]

for eachElement in arrayList:
        fiction(eachElement)
```

I want multiprocess the function under

> for eachElement in arrayList:

So that I can use the multiple cores of my box. All the help is appreciated.

Comment: start by looking into the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing) library...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing) module contains all sorts of basic classes which can be helpful for this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
def f(x):
     return x*x

p = Pool(5)
p.map(f, [1,2,3])
```

And the work will be distributed among 3 processes.

This is fairly simple, but you can achieve much more using an external packages, mostly a [Message-oriented middleware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message-oriented_middleware).

Prime examples are [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org), [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com) and [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org).

RabbitMQ has a combination of good python API and simplicity. You can see [here](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html) how simple it is to create a dispatcher-workers pattern, in which one process is sending the workload, and other processes preform it.

ZeroMQ is a bit more low-level, but is very lightweight and does not require an extenal broker.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Where you say `p.map(f, [1,2,3]))` , I want to pass each element of a list as an. My list looks some what like this `(('1',), ('2',), ('3',), ('4',), ('5',))`. This list is result of a sql query fetchAll(). In order to access each element of the list, I have to do a foreach kind of loop. Can you tell me how to multiprocess under a for each loop or a better way to access all the element of the list and multiprocess it.

Comment: The `map` function just sends iterates over the list and send every item to `f` (aka the tuple `('1',)` will be sent to the first process, and so on).
How to perform you multiprocessing is subjected to the nature of the work `f` is doing, and the amount of control you want of the distribution of work itself. Message-based system scale **much** better, but are harder to configure (the broker) and has some overhead in terms of programmer time (you need to learn the API), latency per-message.

Comment: Thanks it worked. My list was not built properly and it was flipping out because of that. Your suggestion helped me a lot.